# How to set org.gradle.native system property when using the wrapper

Tags: gradle

I would like to set the `org.gradle.native` JVM system property to `false` to disable gradle native integration on our CI system where the OS version does not support it. I have no control over the OS. We use the gradle wrapper which invokes the gradle daemon to do the build.

The relevant gradle code that reads the property [is here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v6.6.1/subprojects/native/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/nativeintegration/services/NativeServices.java#L91). Note that it's a static initialiser - it happens early - this may or may not be relevant. I have tried, without success:

```
./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.native=false
```

```
./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs='-Dorg.gradle.native=false'
```

and also adding to `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/gradle.properties`:

```
systemProp.org.gradle.native=false
```

Comment: I wish there was an answer to this.  My OS is z/OS and it too is not recognized by Gradle native services.  Builds fail with `NativeIntegrationUnavailableException:
SystemInfo is not supported on this operating system.`.

I got to this dead  end because I was forced to update my JRE to 11, which forced me to update my Gradle to 7.4.2.  Now I'm just stuck.  I'm starting to feel like I should have stuck with Ant.